# linq to sql lazyloading not working

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql, lazy-loading

I'm trying to use linq to sql to perform a simple select on a parent entity named Customers which has a one to many relationship in my dbml designer to an entity called Projects.

With a join, I can access the column properties on both entities:

```
using (DataClasses1DataContext DbContext = new DataClasses1DataContext())
            {
                var query2 = DbContext.Customers
                    .Join(DbContext.Projects, c => c.CustomerID, p => p.CustomerID,
                    (c, p) => new
                    {
                        c.Email,
                        p.Customer
                    });
            }
```

However, during a simple select (using any of the query1, 2 or 3 variables), I don't know why the Lazy Loading doesn't show any column properties of the Projects entity (using intellisense).
I know query1 & query2 would return lists and query3 would return just one record.

How can I properly use Lazy Loading and access the column properties in the Project child entity?

Also, why use a JOIN on related entities if I could access those same child columns with Lazy or Eager loading?

```
using (DataClasses1DataContext DbContext = new DataClasses1DataContext())
            {
                //var dataLoadOptions = new DataLoadOptions();
                //DbContext.LoadOptions.LoadWith<Customer>(n => n.Projects);

                //var query1 = DbContext.Customers.Where(c => c.CustomerID > 0);

                //var query2 = DbContext.Customers.Where(c => c.CustomerID > 0).Select(c => new { c.CustomerID, c.Projects });

                var query3 = DbContext.Customers.Where(c => c.CustomerID == 1).FirstOrDefault();

                query3.Projects.
            }
```

Edit #1:
var query1 = DbContext.Customers.Where(c => c.CustomerID > 0);

```
            foreach (var c in query1)
            {
                c.Projects.
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The single object is Customer, but Projects is a collection not a single Project object.

**UPDATE**

```
var query1 = DbContext.Customers.Where(c => c.CustomerID > 0);

foreach (var c in query1)
{
    foreach(var p in c.Projects)
    {
         int id = p.CustomerID;
         ...
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, I see... If that's the case why can't I access the properties of the Projects collection in my saved edit then via query1?

Comment: @sagesky36 Because `c.Projects` is collection of `Project` objects.

Comment: OK, I see.... Makes sense now... So, the only way to get data from multiple entities using one query is to do it via a JOIN --- correct? Is there any way to do something like: Customers.Projects.ProjectID in some kind of statement?

Comment: @sagesky36 Do you want to get `ProjectID`-s of all `Projects` from all `Customers`?

Comment: According to the following link, you can clearly see the author accessing properties from related entities in one statement without iterating through a collection which went back to my original question. I don't know how he can access the properties of the related entities (without iterating through a collection) and I can't (via my original question). If you could shed some light on this, I would greatly appreciate it. Here is the link: http://www.remondo.net/linq-sql-lazy-loading-example-dataloadoptions/

Comment: @sagesky36 `employee.Department.Building.Name;` it s one to one relationship. `Employee` has `Departnet` it has `Building` and `Building` has `Name`. In your case `Customer` has `Projects` (One to many relationship) whish is collection of `Project`.